# HTML5+jQuery+phonegap mobile app security

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile, oauth, restful-authentication

I'm new to this area and I'm developing a `HTML5` mobile app that calls a restful webservices api and exchange JSON objects.

I want to authenticate the client once and give a a key/token that can be used afterwards until a pre-defined expiration date. I have 4 questions:

1. How can I secure the serverside webservices api? any tools whatsoever?
2. Can I use the local storage to store the key/token?
3. What are the phonegap security tools I can use for the client side?
4. How can I use OAUTH in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## How can I secure the serverside webservices api? any tools whatsoever?

OAuth may be overkill for your need, verify that you really need to use such a powerful (and complex) standard.

Two examples of PHP server side software that you may use:

- [Solberg-OAuth](https://github.com/andreassolberg/solberg-oauth)
- [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/)

## Can I use the local storage to store the key/token?

Yes! Be aware that you MUST use the OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow in order to obtain the token at the client side.

## What are the phonegap security tools I can use for the client side?

ChildBrowser is a plugin to open a separate browserwindow for the authentication process.

I've written a javascript library JSO that can do OAuth 2.0 for you. Other libraries exists as well.

- https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso

## How can I use OAUTH in this case?

#### Using JSO with Phonegap and ChildBrowser

Using JSO to perform OAuth 2.0 authorization in WebApps running on mobile devices in hybrid environment is an important deployment scenario for JSO.

Here is a detailed instruction on setting up JSO with Phonegap for iOS and configure OAuth 2.0 with Google. You may use it with Facebook or other OAuth providers as well.

#### Preparations

- Install XCode from App Store, and iOS development kit
- Install [Phonegap 2.0, Cordova 2.0](https://phonegap.com/download/)

#### Setup App

To create a new App

```
./create  /Users/andreas/Sites/cordovatest no.erlang.test "CordovaJSOTest"
```

#### Install ChildBrowser

The original ChildBrowser plugin is available here.

- https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

However, it is *not* compatible with Cordova 2.0. Instead, you may use this fork of ChildBrowser which should be working with Cordova 2.0:

- https://github.com/Shereef/ChildBrowserOnCordova200

What you need to do is to copy these files:

- https://github.com/Shereef/ChildBrowserOnCordova200/tree/master/ChildBrowserOnCordova200/Plugins

in to your WebApp project area, by using drag and drop into the Plugins folder in XCode.

Now you need to edit the file found in `Resources/Cordova.plist` found in your WebApp project area.

In this file you need to add one array entry with '*' into ExternalHosts, and two entries into Plugins:

- ChildBrowser -> ChildBrowser.js
- ChildBrowserCommand -> ChildBrowserCommand

as seen on the screenshot.

[image]
<sub>(source: [erlang.no](http://clippings.erlang.no/ZZ6D3C032F.jpg))</sub>

#### Setting up your WebApp with ChildBrowser

I'd suggest to test and verify that you get ChildBrowser working before moving on to the OAuth stuff.

In your `index.html` file try this, and verify using the Simulator.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ChildBrowser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var deviceready = function() {
        if(window.plugins.childBrowser == null) {
            ChildBrowser.install();
        }
        window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://google.com");
    };

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, false);

</script>
```

#### Setting up JSO

Download the latest version of JSO:

- https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso

The documentation on JSO is available there as well.

The callback URL needs to point somewhere, and one approach would be to put a callback HTML page somewhere, it does not really matter where, although a host you trust. And put a pretty blank page there:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>OAuth Callback endpoint</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Processing OAuth response...
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, setup your application index page. Here is a working example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ChildBrowser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jso/jso.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var deviceready = function() {

        var debug = true;

        /*
         * Setup and install the ChildBrowser plugin to Phongap/Cordova.
         */
        if(window.plugins.childBrowser == null) {
            ChildBrowser.install();
        }

        // Use ChildBrowser instead of redirecting the main page.
        jso_registerRedirectHandler(window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage);

        /*
         * Register a handler on the childbrowser that detects redirects and
         * lets JSO to detect incomming OAuth responses and deal with the content.
         */
        window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function(url){
            url = decodeURIComponent(url);
            console.log("Checking location: " + url);
            jso_checkfortoken('facebook', url, function() {
                console.log("Closing child browser, because a valid response was detected.");
                window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
            });
        };

        /*
         * Configure the OAuth providers to use.
         */
        jso_configure({
            "facebook": {
                client_id: "myclientid",
                redirect_uri: "https://myhost.org/callback.html",
                authorization: "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth",
                presenttoken: "qs"
            }
        }, {"debug": debug});

        // For debugging purposes you can wipe existing cached tokens...
        // jso_wipe();

        // jso_dump displays a list of cached tokens using console.log if debugging is enabled.
        jso_dump();

        // Perform the protected OAuth calls.
        $.oajax({
            url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/home",
            jso_provider: "facebook",
            jso_scopes: ["read_stream"],
            jso_allowia: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Response (facebook):");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    };

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, false);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply including the codes and links... Web services api and the back end is java. I was trying to use wso2 api manager to publish the services, but still checking the feasibility. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

**How can I secure the serverside webservices api? any tools whatsoever?**
Depends on which language the web service is written, php has zend framework for creating web services / nusoap etc. So all of the languages do provide info on how to secure the webservice.

**Can I use the local storage to store the key/token?** 
Yes you can use local storage look at the phonegap [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage)

**What are the phonegap security tools I can use for the client side?** 
I dont think so there are any but you can search for some plugins or create your own plugin. Depends on what kind of security do you want to implement.

**How can I use OAUTH in this case?**
Here is a library for [OAuth](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) and this seems to be helpful. You can create a phone gap plugin to interact with the library or use a javascript [oauth library](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/)(its with sample also).

Comment: Thank you and back end is written in Java